# Why am I getting wrong outpu with this php code?

Tags: php

Its returning garbage output. I am newbie to PHP. Please help me out with this one. I don't want to remain stuck in this forever. I am new to Object oriented programming so I am unable to figureout what went wrong and where!

```
 <?php
    Abstract class Employee {
        protected $Fname;
        protected $Lname;
        protected $dept;
        static protected $total= '0';
        public abstract function getSalary();
        function __construct($f,$l,$d) {
            $this->Fname = $f;
            $this->Lname = $l;
            $this->dept = $d;
            self::$total++;
        }
        public function getFullname () {
        return $this->Fname." ".$this->Lname;       
        }
        public function getDept() {
        return $this->dept; 
        }
        public static function getTotal(){
            return self::$total;
        }
    }
    class FullTime extends Employee {
        protected $Annualsalary;
        function __construct($s) {
            $this->Annualsalary = $s;
        }
        public function getSalary() {
            return $this->Annualsalary / 12; 
        }
    }
    class Contract extends Employee {
        protected $Monthlypay;
        function __construct ($s)
        {
            $this->Monthlypay = $s;
        }
        public function getSalary() {
            return $this->Monthlypay;
        
        }
    }
    
    
        $emp1 = new FullTime("John",'Doe','IT',150000);
        $emp2 = new FullTime('J','Doe','sales',130000);
        $emp3 = new FullTime('John','D','sales',140000);
        $emp4= new Contract('JOHAN','Doe','sales',14000);
        echo "Total Employees  = ".Employee::getTotal()."<br>";
        echo $emp1->getFullname()." | ".$emp1->getDept()." | ".$emp1->getSalary()."<br>";
        echo $emp2->getFullname()." | ".$emp2->getDept()." | ".$emp2->getSalary()."<br>";
        echo $emp3->getFullname()." | ".$emp3->getDept()." | ".$emp3->getSalary()."<br>";
        echo $emp4->getFullname()." | ".$emp4->getDept()." | ".$emp4->getSalary();
        ?>
```

Output

> Total Employees = 0
>
> | | 0
>
> | | 0
>
> | | 0
>
> | | JOHAN

Comment: Could you please explain what your problem actually is?

Comment: What error are you getting actually?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look and help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You need to initialize every class property, PHP will not do that automatically. Just call the constructor-function in the parent class. Also, you need to pass all parameters to the constructors.

Have a look at this:

```html
<?php
    
    Abstract class Employee {
        protected $Fname;
        protected $Lname;
        protected $dept;
        static protected $total = 0;
    
        public abstract function getSalary();
    
        function __construct($f, $l, $d) {
            $this->Fname = $f;
            $this->Lname = $l;
            $this->dept = $d;
            self::$total++;
        }
    
        public function getFullname() {
            return $this->Fname . " " . $this->Lname;
        }
    
        public function getDept() {
            return $this->dept;
        }
    
        public static function getTotal() {
            return self::$total;
        }
    }
    
    class FullTime extends Employee {
        protected $Annualsalary;
    
        function __construct($f, $l, $d, $s) {
            parent::__construct($f, $l, $d);
            $this->Annualsalary = $s;
        }
    
        public function getSalary() {
            return $this->Annualsalary / 12;
        }
    }
    
    class Contract extends Employee {
        protected $Monthlypay;
    
        function __construct($f, $l, $d, $s) {
            parent::__construct($f, $l, $d);
            $this->Monthlypay = $s;
        }
    
        public function getSalary() {
            return $this->Monthlypay;
    
        }
    }
    
    
    $emp1 = new FullTime("John", 'Doe', 'IT', 150000);
    $emp2 = new FullTime('J', 'Doe', 'sales', 130000);
    $emp3 = new FullTime('John', 'D', 'sales', 140000);
    $emp4 = new Contract('JOHAN', 'Doe', 'sales', 14000);
    
    echo "Total Employees  = " . Employee::getTotal() . "<br>";
    echo $emp1->getFullname() . " | " . $emp1->getDept() . " | " . $emp1->getSalary() . "<br>";
    echo $emp2->getFullname() . " | " . $emp2->getDept() . " | " . $emp2->getSalary() . "<br>";
    echo $emp3->getFullname() . " | " . $emp3->getDept() . " | " . $emp3->getSalary() . "<br>";
    echo $emp4->getFullname() . " | " . $emp4->getDept() . " | " . $emp4->getSalary();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You, sir, are awesome. I was also confused with passing arguments from child class as well. This made my concepts clear. Mad respect for you.

Answer (score 0):

__constructor is overriden in FullTime class but does not call parent constructor

```
function __construct($f,$l,$d, $s) {
 parent::__construct($f,$l,$d);
 $this->Annualsalary = $s;
}
```